# Super Activity class dialog box listeners handling in sub class activity

Tags: android, android-dialog

Hi I have created generic Activity class which have a dialog box(with DatePicker) in it. Extending it allover the application. I would like to handle the listeners of the date selector in sub class activity.
I tried with implementing a interface in the super class and override the same in sub class. and i was struck at overriding the same in sub class.

Now my question is.. .Is this really a bad idea...? Any alternate for this approach.

Comment: interface is proper way in this case.

Comment: @Biraj Zalavadia: Can you please give me any snippet on this please.

Comment: post your code of BaseActivity.java and any SubActivity.java I will change in your code.

Comment: @ Biraj Zalavadia: Thank you very much. I solved it and posted my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution to my question
All you have to do is create a abstract method is super class as

```
public abstract class SuperActivity{

onCreateDialog(){
//date picker with date select listeners and add  get the selected date;
// call onDateChanged() in the date selected listener in the super class
}
public abstract onDateChanged(); 
}
```

Implement the onDateChanged() method in SubClass
Then whenever you changed the date in super class.. sub class onDateChanged() method will be called.

```
class SubCActivity extends SuperActivity(){

public void onDateChanged(){
// handling
}
}
```